# .net core & microsoft identity framework and Azure AD multiple authentication schemes

Tags: c#, azure, openid-connect

I'd like to implement azure ad's oauth authentication using Microsoft.Identity.Web => MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilder
I can successfully make it work with the tutorials provided by microsoft however I want to enable multi login providers with Identity.web, I'd like Azure AD + local SQL server(already implemented) in case azure ad is not available for X user.

I tried to do it by setting up a default scheme and a defaultchallenge to redirect to a view, but I get the following error:
InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Cookies

Any advice? :) Thank you

PS: I've realised what I want to achieve with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect, but I'd like to make it work with Microsoft.Identity.Web

What I tried to use Microsoft.Identity.Web and multiple scheme
[image: What I tried]

Working without possibility to choose the scheme desired
[image: What I know is working.]

Working with the possibility to choose the scheme desired
[image: openidconnect]

**UPDATE:**

What I tried after Dennis's recommendations:
I don't have the error "scheme already exist", but I'm not beign redirected to my login page.
[image: configure through authentication options]

Comment: So, the issue is related to the fact that you're doing "AddCookie" and then calling ConfigureApplicationCookie on the AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp. They both probably default to the Cookies scheme. I wonder if you really need to call AddCookie when you're using the AddMicrosoftIdenity, so try and remove the AddCookie part.

Comment: if I remove .addCookie( options => ...) I still get the error: Scheme already exists: Cookies

Comment: Right, now also remove the ConfigureApplicationCookie. The set-up of the cookie needs to happen within the scope of the AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp, not after. There is an overload for you to use: `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(AuthenticationBuilder, Action<MicrosoftIdentityOptions>, Action<CookieAuthenticationOptions>, String, String, Boolean)`

Comment: I just updated my post, I don't understand why I need to add those 2 extra parameters (openidconnect2 and cookies2).
Also I'm not being redirected to my login page now. :/

Comment: Just to be sure, to trigger the redirect to the login page you need to use `services.AddAuthorization()` as well as `app.UseAuthorization()`, have you done that?

Comment: Yes I have app.useAuthorization setup with some policies, tried to remove them to check (didn't work), and also have the app.useAuthorization()

Comment: Is it working? I have same problem.